# How to deploy a angular project using Jenkins in windows

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I'm trying to deploy an angular project using Jenkins. In the window bash, I used the command **npm install** and **npm run ng -- build** to install packages and to build the project. Later when I try to host using http-server it throws an error like **'http-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command**, and it clearly shows it is not supporting any Angular-related commands in it. Suggest me anyway to solve this. Thanks in advance
[image]